# Show that $(x)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (the polynomials with integer coefs) which is not maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I showed that if $(x)$ is  prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then since 
$\mathbb{Z}[x] /(x)$ is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, so $(x)$ is not maximal. But when I want to show that $(x)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ I've got stuck... How could I show?
The old proofs doesn't give any isomorphic function! my question is a particular case, not a theorem (just for more info)

Comment: Please don't change your question after answers have been posted. Ask a new question instead if need be

Comment: You can find proofs in many prior answers, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685431/how-to-prove-ideal-i-is-prime-iff-a-i-is-a-integral-domain/685455#685455) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052380/prove-that-i-subseteq-r-is-prime-if-and-only-if-r-i-is-an-integral-domain/1052392#1052392)

Comment: @bill Dubuque edited

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain. And $A/I$ is a domain if and only if $I$ is a prime ideal.